# Is there anyway to get the rows count of current tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Not `visibleCells`, the total rows count.

I know there is a datasource array, but is it possible to obtain without concerning data?

Somebody said this question statement is unclear, so update **my situation**: I want to insert some rows into tableView, one common way is reassemble the datasource array then use `[tableView reloadData]` to refresh whole tableView, but I don't wanna do this because of user experiments. Instead I try to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` method to just insert the new rows, so one must-do thing is to create the indexPaths. I choose `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:]`, so you know I should get the previous number of rows then generate indexPaths array and before invoking `insertRowsAtindexPaths:withRowAnimation:` update the datasource array. It is important for opportunity to update the datasource array by this way. It sucks i think, so I'm a little curious "Is there anyway to get the rows count of current tableView?"

Comment: Ask the table view how many sections it has and how many rows in each section (see the docs for `UITableView`).

Comment: Vote to repopen. It's not the best question but it's certainly not unclear. Besides, the question had three answers and one was accepted before it was closed. So obviously it was clear enough to lots of people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the total number of rows in your table view, loop through each section in the table view and increment the `rowCount` by the number of rows in the current section:

```
NSInteger rowCount = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0 ; i < tableView.numberOfSections ; i ++) {
    rowCount += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion - change `i` and `rowCount` from `int` to `NSInteger`.

Comment: @rmaddy Sure..since tableview.numberOfSections is an NSInteger. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Seems wrong to ask the tableview for the number of rows it has rather than the data source.

Comment: @Abizern You should probably tell the OP that.

Comment: The OP doesn't care or doesn't know. I feel it's better to guide in the right direction rather than providing a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

swift version : `yourTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)`

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3:

```
func getAllRowCount()->Int{
    var rowCount = 0
    for index in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections-1{
        rowCount += self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: index)
    }
    return rowCount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `[TableView numberOfRowsInSection:yourSection];`

Comment: You can specify your section here.

Answer (score -3):

If all your table rows have the same height, then you probably can go:

```
row count = tableView.contentSize.height / tableView.rowHeight
```

But if you're tableView has different row heights, I can't help you :D

Comment: This code also assumes there is no table header or footer and no section headers or footers, in addition to all rows having the same height.